# jQuery trigger click for function with e.target

Tags: jquery, eventtrigger

I've had issues with the jQuery `.trigger()` in the past, sometimes it works and others not.  It usually breaks down when I need it to do something like this ...

**HTML**

```
<div class="list">
  <a href="#" class="one">one</a>
  <a href="#" class="two">two</a>
  <a href="#" class="three">three</a>
</div>

<p class="output"></p>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.two').trigger('click');

   $('.list a').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $text = $(e.target).text();
      $('.output').text($text);
   });
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7pup2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to register the handler first then trigger the event

it should be

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('.list a').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $text = $(e.target).text();
      $('.output').text($text);
   });

   $('.two').trigger('click');
});
```